# The local project works correctly, but it does not find the url's server

Tags: laravel

I created a project, it works perfectly in the local. It worked sometimes on the server.

but most of the time on certain pages does not find, for example:

on the login button that I clicked.

Is there a problem with the code or the host that I have provided?

Comment: what is the version of laravel?

Comment: laravel version : 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update composer on server thats why sometime button links not working

```
Composer update
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
```

Delete all the cache file i.e.

```
 storage/framework/views
```

Comment: here is command for clear view as well no need for manual delete this `php artisan view:clear `

Answer (score 1):

Kindly make sure that .htaccess file locatedin same directory where index.php is located

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss .env file. You should check the .env file is exist and valid .